# Can metal framed single pane windows be sandwiched together to make an effective double pane?

Tags: windows

I recently purchased 10   4' x 10' single pane glass windows in metal frames. They were an indoor glass-walled conference room. Is there a way to stick two of them together to create a double pane and vent them so condensation isn't a problem? I'd like to use them as windows in a shop I'm building.

Comment: Instead of venting them, you could seal them and put some desiccant packs in to absorb any trapped moisture. This is just a thought I am throwing out there. I have not tried this, but I think condensation IS going to be a problem unless you somehow dry the air trapped in between.

Comment: Adding storm windows achieves much the same effect without making the whole window system ungainly.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you can make a double-pane window, but so far as thermal insulating properties go, you are highly unlikely to achive anything of value. External storm windows serve to keep rain/snow off the window proper but do almost nothing to insulate (unless of course the interior window leaks like crazy and the storm window doesn't).
Sealed double-pane insulating windows are specifically designed with fluid dynamics in mind.  Aside from filling the gap with a dry inert gas, the spacing is carefully selected.  A very thin spacing will allow too much direct conduction heat loss thru the gas.  Too large a spacing will allow internal vortices to form, leading to large convection heat loss.

In sum, unless you dig up the proper spacing specs and are able to match them in your construction, you won't get much additional thermal insulation. You may get added sound insulation, if that matters.

Comment: Not to mention concerns about contained moisture in the sandwiched air causing unsightly condensation. Making conventional double-pane windows is quite the sophisticated process. Many companies go through quite an expensive and relatively high tech process to build theirs.